# How to move (translate) an image by an offset of X, Y on imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, move, offset

What's the command that will take an image, move / translate it by an offset of X,Y pixels and save the result?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try something like this:

`convert test.png -page +20+20 -background none -flatten newtest.png`

where `+20+20` represent your x,y coordinates.

Comment: Does not work on tiff images if the offsets are negative :/